# angular cli exclude files/directory for `ng test --code-coverage`

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-cli, istanbul

I am running the following command to unit test and generate code code coverage report.

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

It is working fine and writing code coverage report in `coverage` folder.

In this I got all files and directory coverage report

[image]

But I want to exclude specific files/directory let say `src/app/quote/services/generated`. How to do that?

Comment: update with the code that shows this table data.

Comment: There is no code for table data. This is the coverage report is being generated by Karma Istanbul Coverage Reporter. The Command I shared is generating the report.

Comment: Can anyone please help.

Comment: Hi @ParthaSarathiGhosh, I'm facing similar issues. In my case, I've spec files and I want to skip those files and thus get code coverage without them.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

### Updated September 2019

With Angular CLI 6, angular-cli.json has been renamed to angular.json which contains the configuration. In `angular.json`, `codeCoverage` expects a boolean value, which sets whether code-coverage should be done with every test run or not. To exclude files from code coverage, there is a property `codeCoverageExclude` which accepts an array of files to be excluded from code coverage.

`angular.json`

```
"test": {
  "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/assets/vendor/**"],,
  ...
}
```

### Updated answer

`rc.0` has been released. You should be able to add the code snippet below to ignore files.

### Original answer

Currently, you aren't able to do so in `beta.32.3`. A change is coming to allow this to happen. In the next release (probably `rc.0`), you will be able to do the following:

`.angular-cli.json`

```
"test": {
  "codeCoverage": {
    "exclude": [
      "src/app/quote/services/generated/**/*"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. How do you came to know that? Is there any release plan. Please post the link here.

Comment: I proposed the solution that Filipe Silva ultimately implemented. The [changeset](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/b6893d0b7fb351baf2ae499decb7740411305ef5) is already in `master`. It will be in the next CLI release, whether it's called `beta.33` or `RC.0`. The next CLI release will happen after Angular itself reaches `RC.0`.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh `RC.0` has been released. If you upgrade your project, you should be able to use my answer.

Comment: Here is a similar type of question for `ng lint`. Please have a look if you can help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507838/angular-cli-exclude-fiels-directory-for-ng-linit

Comment: For newer versions of Angular (6 and up I think) see the other answer in this question.  it is now `codeCoverageExclude` instead!

Comment: @delasteve do you know how to exclude all files ending with .action.ts, because your answer is specific by folder? correct me if im wrong. thanks in advace

Comment: `codeCoverageExclude` should actually be inside `test.options` as stated by @Greg in another answer

Comment: I'm using Angular 14 and codeCoverageExclude stopped working

Comment: @ÁlisterLopesFerreira Same here.

Answer (score 72):

With the latest CLI, inside angular.json

```
  "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/testing/**/*"],
```

Comment: In case anyone else is having trouble with this in a library inside a monorepo, it is worth noting that the directory is specified from the root, ie `"projects/lib-something/lib/foldertoexclude/*"`.

Comment: I'm using Angular 13 and codeCoverageExclude stopped working.\