# Exclude *.component.ts files from test coverage using Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

[image: app_component_Coverage]

I want to exclude all the component.ts files from my test coverage and cover only service.ts files in any level of subfolder.
I have tried number of options commented out in the below code snippet but none worked for me.
Seeking help from experts to achieve my goal.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      // '**/*.service.ts'
    ],
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage/new-tts-ui'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    preprocessors: {
      //'**/*.service.ts': ['coverage']
      //'**/*!(component).js' : ['coverage']  
     // '**/*.service.ts': ['coverage']
    },
    port: 9876,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    //exclude: ['/**/*.component.ts','/**/*.component.js']
    //exclude: ['src/*/{*.js,!(src)/**/*.service.ts}']
    exclude: ['**/*.component.ts', '**/*.component.js']
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[angular.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L1065-L1267) has section **codeCoverageExclude** where you can specify array of patterns to ignore

Comment: Been looking for this for a long time. Thanks! I then found a fuller description with the updates to angular.json, but VSCode will also tell you how to insert this in:

projects > mars > architect > test > options > codeCoverage/codeCoverageExclude

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241654/angular-cli-exclude-files-directory-for-ng-test-code-coverage