# Exclude protractor files from ng test command

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, karma-jasmine

In my project we have unit tests files which ends with .spec.ts and protractor test cases which ends with .prot.spec.ts. Now when I run command 'ng test' my protractor files get picked up because it also has the same extention (.spec.ts) but I dont want them to execute. I tried adding the properties like 'exclude' in tsconfig.json, tsconfig.app.json, test.js but it seems that its not working.

I need to know what is the exact place where I can put my configuration so that my protractor files will be excluded.

Please find the screenshots below :

[tsConfig.spec.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id234.png)

[test.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvr5d.png)

[tsconfig.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcyp8.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0PoR.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241654/angular-cli-exclude-files-directory-for-ng-test-code-coverage

Comment: @Indragith : we cannot add the 'exclude' property in angular.json, It gives following error. Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(exclude).

Comment: You could change the names of your protractor tests to prot.test.ts and then have the protractor configuration file point to *.test.ts. Then ng-test should only pick up karma tests and ng-e2e should pick up protractor tests.

Comment: @SankalanParajuli : Yup, Thats the last option. Thank you!

Comment: @pritampanhale: If I am not wrong, with the latest angular cli version you should add the codeCoverageExclude: ['specify the path here'] instead of codeCoverage: { exclude : [] }

Comment: I moved the protractor files to some other folder and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in your test.js, change the glob in the context

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /^((?!prot).)*\.spec.ts$/);
```