# Angular CLI: Exclude Methods and Portions from Ng Test Code Coverage

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner, istanbul, angular10

I am running the following command to unit test and generate code code coverage report.

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

How do I exclude certain methods and portions of files from code coverage? This answer excludes Whole file, I just want to exclude a portion, class method etc.

[angular cli exclude files/directory for `ng test --code-coverage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241654/angular-cli-exclude-files-directory-for-ng-test-code-coverage)

```
"test": {
  "codeCoverageExclude": ["src/assets/vendor/**"],,
  ...
}
```

Comment: are you using jasmine to do tests?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do that? I believe code coverage is more informative if it includes all the line of code, though you can have a look at `xdescribe` and `xit`